# Как синхронизировать чат-бота Вконтакте с Dialogflow?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот, dialogflow

Помогите синхронизировать данные из Чат-бота Вконтакте и Dialogflow. Прикладываю

```py
def write_msg(user_id, ans):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'ans': send_message(result), 'random_id': random.randint(0, 2048)})

#Авторизация в Dialogflow
apiai.ApiAI('510f2d1483e240818cb83edb5fb245d6')

# API-ключ созданный ранее
token = #api-токен с группы ВКонтакте
# Авторизация как сообщество
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
# Работа с сообщениями
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
print("Бот запущен")
# ОСНОВНОЙ ЦИКЛ
for event in longpoll.listen():
    # Если пришло новое сообщение
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:    
        # Если оно имеет метку для меня( то есть бота)
        if event.to_me:     
            # Сообщение от пользователя
            request = event.text

def response_to_user(MESSAGE_NEW):
    # Токен API к Dialogflow
    request = apiai.ApiAI('510f2d1483e240818cb83edb5fb245d6').text_request()
    # Язык запроса
    request.lang = 'ru'
    # ID Сессии диалога (необходимы для обучения бота)
    request.session_id = 'Test'
    # Отправка запроса к серверу с сообщением от пользователя
    request.query = message.text
    # Получаем ответ от сервера и декодируем в utf-8
    response_json = json.loads(request.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))
    # Достаём ответ ИИ
    response_from_ai = response_json['result']['fulfillment']['speech']
    vk.send_message(user_id, response_from_ai)
```

пока вот такой вид, разобранный. Отдельно чат-бот ВК работает. Dialogflow тоже работает с Telegramm. Помогите связать с Вконтакте.

Comment: Совет: вместо `random.randint(0, 2048)` воспользуйтесь `random.getrandbits(64)`.

Comment: у меня не получилось все равно сделать, хотя я использовал random.getrandbits(64)

Comment: Это было не решение, а просто совет. Использовать 64-х битное псевдослучайное число правильнее, чем использовать 11-ти битное.

Comment: Получилось сделать? Тоже мучаюсь с этим

Comment: к сожалению пока нет(